# ¿Cómo instalar un paquete Python mediante carpeta?

Tags: python

Quiero hacer uso de un paquete en python 3.6, como por ejemplo *termcolor*. Tengo el paquete ya en una carpeta pero no sé en dónde debo colocar la carpeta para poder importar el paquete con el comando import.

Comment: ¿Por qué no lo instalas con pip? En este caso, dado que es un módulo en Python puro basta con que coloques el archivo `termcolor.py` en el mismo directorio de trabajo en el que está tu script que lo va a importar.

Comment: Muchas gracias FJSevilla, olvidé comentar que no lo puedo instalar con pip debido a la seguridad y restricciones empresariales de mi equipo de computo.

Comment: PakinJa entiendo, si solo son problemas de permisos y usas Python 3 considerar  seriamente crear un entorno virtual en un directorio donde tengas plenos permisos y usar pip para instalar en él lo que quieras con normalidad. Menciono lo de Python 3 porque puedes usar [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) sin necesidad de instalar nada para crear el entorno. En cualquier caso siempre es buena práctica aislar un proyecto en un entorno virtual y no tocar la instalación del sistema. Un saludo

Comment: Por cierto, se puede hacer que `pip` instale un paquete en cualquier directorio usando `--target`: `pip install --target=\ruta\al\directorio nombre_del_paquete`, otra cosa es que luego a la hora de importar este directorio debe estar en el PYTHONPATH para que el import pueda ser resuelto con éxito. Si no tienes problemas con lo de crear un entorno hazlo, una cosa es Termcolor y otra paquetes complejos como NumPy, Pandas, Django, etc con múltiples dependencias y partes en C , C++ o incluso Fortran que se han de compilar...

Comment: Gracias @FJSevilla, de hecho quiero instalar _tensorflow_ para este cuento con el _whl_ pero otras dependencias como _termcolor_, _gast_, etc. las tengo en carpetas que obtuve al descargar y descomprimir cada una. Ahora no sé donde colocar dichas carpetas  _termcolor_ etc. para poder instarlar tensorflow con whl